# Saving temporary arraylist for using in Adapter

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-adapter

I have a problem.
I need to save an `ArrayList` before I'll remove some elements.
Therefore I use additional "users opied" `ArrayList`  with duplicates of "users" ArrayList.
But it not works, I don't now why.
After I remove some elements in "users" `ArrayList` , that action affects also on "usersCopied" `ArrayList`.
How get rid of this problem? 
I wanna save initial list, and not change it, that list I'll use for restoring initial data.
Thanks!

```
public class SelectUser extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public static ArrayList<com.taxizauglom.utils.User> users;
public static ArrayList<com.taxizauglom.utils.User> usersCopied;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    users = new ArrayList<>();
    // copy of users list, not changing
    usersCopied = null;

    mCallback = new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<com.taxizauglom.utils.User>>() {
        @Override
        public Loader<ArrayList<com.taxizauglom.utils.User>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            progressDialog.show();
            return new GetUser(getApplicationContext());
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<com.taxizauglom.utils.User>> loader, ArrayList<com.taxizauglom.utils.User> data) {
            users = data;
            adapter = new MyListAdapter(users);
            listUsers.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Copying data
            if (usersCopied == null){
                Log.d(Constants.tag, "Not copied!");
                copyData(data);
            } else
            {
                Log.d(Constants.tag, "Already copied!");
            }
        }
    };

    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, mCallback).forceLoad(); 
}

public void copyData(ArrayList<com.taxizauglom.utils.User> data) {
    usersCopied = new ArrayList<>(data);
}
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<User> users;

    public MyListAdapter(ArrayList<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // here is a problem
        //After removing item from "users" list, in list "usersCopied" also was removed that element. Why?
        Log.d(Constants.tag, String.valueOf("MyListAdapter users.size: " + users.size()));
        Log.d(Constants.tag, String.valueOf("MyListAdapter usersCopied.size: " + usersCopied.size()));
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnSort:
            sortData();
            break;
    }
}

// I wanna remove element only in list users
//restoring initial data from "userCopied" list
//and removing from "users" list
public void sortData() {
    adapter.users = usersCopied;
    adapter.users.remove(0);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're still referencing the user data.
To be sure you're not referencing anymore, change your copyData method:

```
public void copyData(ArrayList<com.taxizauglom.utils.User> data) {
    usersCopied = new ArrayList<com.taxizauglom.utils.User>();
    for (User user : data){
        //Use the data from this loop's user to create a new one.
        usersCopied.add(new User(....)); 
    }
}
```

It seems unnecessary, but unless you create new objects of User, you will keep the reference in tact.

Comment: Collections.copy(destination, source); will further optimize it. As you need need iterate over your source list.

Answer (score 0):

okay I had faced the same issue.
1. Try creating another temporary arraylist. 
2. temporary alist = data;
3. And then do users.addall(alist).

Hope this helps.

Comment: you can just use the constructor that takes as parameters collection `new ArrayList(Collection....)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Collections.copy(destination, source);`

Answer (score 0):

try this

create new array list and copy elements from original arraylist to new one using method addAll this will solve your problem.

```
public void copyData(ArrayList<com.taxizauglom.utils.User> data) {
    usersCopied = new ArrayList<com.taxizauglom.utils.User>();
    usersCopied.addAll(data);
}
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, you should include an explanation on why this code would solve OP's issue instead of posing a code-only answer.  Code-only answers are allowed, but including comments & explanations will improve it.

Comment: Code is self explanatory

Comment: To you and I sure, maybe it does, but to OP-- not necessarily, which is why the question is being asked in the first place.  Be aware that the only reason I came across your answer is because other users have flagged it for the VLQ queue.

Answer (score 0):

Create a seperate class for Items that you want to save
e.g. you want to save

`1) ID
2) Name
3) School`

than create a class

```
public class ShowItems{
    public String ID;
    public String NAME;
    public String SCHOOL;

    public ShowItems(String textID, String textNAME, String textSCHOOL) {
        ID = textID;
        NAME = textNAME;
        SCHOOL = textSCHOOL;
    }   
}
```

Now Create an `ArrayList` with type `ShowItems` like this

```
  ArrayList<ShowItems> products = new ArrayList<ShowItems>();
```

And Add the Data like

```
 products.add("1", "MADDY", "CONVENT SCHOOL");
```

If you wanna fetch data at some position, do it like

```
String strID = products.get(position).ID;
String strNAME = products.get(position).NAME;
String strSCHOOL = products.get(position).SCHOOL;
```

Wanna delete items at specific position...?
Not a problem do like this....

```
products.remove(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for advice!
I have found a trouble.

It was there:

```
public void sortData() {
//Here i refer to temporary list, and change it all the time.
adapter.users = usersCopied;
//Instead of I had to use this:
adapter.users = new ArrayList<>(usersCopied); 
    adapter.users.remove(0);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```